# Changing Multiple Text String Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, automation, file-get-contents

```
$content = Get-Content("d:\gfile.txt")
$content = $content.Replace("sometext", "replacedtext")
$content | Out-File "d:\newfile.txt"
```

This works for me - really good - I can convert SQL files to this. Using `Read-Host` I can store the new database info in a variable for the global varible settings in the script.

What I need to work out is - how can I do this for multiple strings in the same variable without running this for each replacement string?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... can you clarify? Probably worth including some sample input and desired output. Ta!

Comment: The thing is, i see multiple posts for use of -Replace - How do you input or replace entire large chunks of elements in XML though, i.e. starting with < Massive section />

Comment: That still doesn't clarify things. Perhaps a proper example with inputs and desired outputs would help illustrate your problem.